# Is this a Black Hat technique?

Tags: html, css, seo

I have found this part of code all over an e-shop:

```
<h1 style="text-indent:-5000px;padding:0;margin:0;position:absolute">....text-in-here...</h1>
```

It was hidden under every product-service image-url.

So is this Black Hat technique?

Comment: No, It is a way to hide stuff on the web page that may be displayed later or will be used by people with limited vision.

Comment: Depends on what `....text-in-here...` is and what is actually shown.

Comment: For screenreaders don't we use <alt> text? 

It's one of the most famous black hat technique to hide text with white color or with css. text-indent isn't that? 

In what case it would be black hat? If the h1 was containing keywords?

Comment: Again, the technique *itself* indicates nothing, whether it's "black hat" or not it depends on the actual content. For example, the heading text is "NIKE ADIDAS REEBOK HARRY POTTER WORLD OF WARCRAFT MAKE MONEY ONLINE" but the user is actually shown "Welcome to the website!". But yes, it can be used as a black hat SEO technique.

Comment: Is there an actual problem we can help you with though? Are you working on this site or are just a customer?

Comment: I am trying to help a friend with his SEO-owner of another site and he told me that the owner of this e-shop with the "text-indent" was playing "dirty" and he would like to find if he is using black hat technique also.

in the h1 is "Offers Masaz the-City, near famousHotel | BrandName Spa & Beauty

And the Product-service it is this spa.

So if it is not black hat technique is it white hat? Because of the usage of h1 it is increasing the SEO of this page right?

Comment: "Offers Masaz the-City, near famousHotel | BrandName Spa & Beauty". I didn't put real names. Is there a tool to search for black hat technique or i have to read the code? Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: It's in greek..http://www.dealsafari.gr/

Comment: -----EDIT------

Check also the <style type="text/css"> there are several classes with display:none properties or top:-10000px. I am not sure what are those for..

Comment: @DrNio i wouldn't really categorize it as black hat SEO because the text in there is the actual title of the linked page (*the one you get if you click the link*)..

Comment: You would get better answers at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com though.. StackOverflow is for programming issues..

Comment: Thank you all! And thanks for the link Gaby I didn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a blackhat technique.

> In search engine optimization (SEO) terminology, Black Hat SEO refers to the use of aggressive SEO strategies, techniques and tactics that focus only on search engines and not a human audience, and usually does not obey search engines rules. Some examples of Black Hat SEO techniques include keyword stuffing, invisible text and doorway pages. (webopedia)

As the content cannot be seen from text-indent tag, it focuses on the Search Engine rather than the human user. Techniques that are far less obviously Search Engine ONLY oriented have been banned by Google. The ALT tag was created for this purpose. Using HTML code for anything that was not intended to be indexed for SEO, should be avoided.